# Set default Launcher in AOSP Source

Tags: android, android-source, android.mk

I have added my launcher along with Launcher3 in AOSP build, On boot up device asks to select default Home app(launcher).

How can I set the my launcher as a default launcher from ASOP source code, so device not ask to select default Home app(launcher) on boot.

I'm aware about LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES but I need both launcher in final build.

Answer (score 1):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` of your home app, you can set the priority of the launcher intent filter to a higher value.

Official documentation: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element#:%7E:text=app%20manifest%20overview.-,android%3Apriority,-The%20priority%20given)